# When using VideoCapture::set the actual fps is much lower than the specified fps

Tags: c++, opencv

A similar question has been asked before, but I'm reposting it in more detail.

I am trying to specify the format of the webcam with VideoCapture::set.

When viewed through a commercial webcam capture program, my webcam supports the following formats.

1920 X 1080 30FPS

1280 X 720 60 FPS

640 X 480 120.101 FPS

.
.
.

However, when the above format is specified in code, the actual FPS is much lower.

1920 X 1080 5FPS

1280 X 720 10FPS

640 X 480 30FPS

Here is my code.

```
#include "stdio.h"

#include <iostream>

#include "windows.h"
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#pragma comment(lib, "opencv/lib/x64/opencv_world320")

int main()
{

printf("Somebody Help Me\n");


cv::VideoCapture capCv(0);
cv::Mat     mMat;


capCv.set(cv::CAP_PROP_FPS, 120.101);
capCv.set(cv::CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 640);
capCv.set(cv::CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 480);
capCv.set(cv::CAP_PROP_FOURCC, CV_FOURCC('M', 'J', 'P', 'G'));


INT64 pTime = 0;
int fps = 0;


while (1)
{

    INT64 sTime = GetTickCount64();


    if(capCv.isOpened())    capCv.read(mMat);


    fps++;

    if (sTime - pTime > 1000)
    {
        pTime = sTime;
        printf("  %.2f X %.2f    %.1f(%d)  \n", capCv.get(cv::CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH), capCv.get(cv::CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT), capCv.get(cv::CAP_PROP_FPS), fps);
        fps = 0;
    }


    cv::imshow("asd", mMat);


    if (cvWaitKey(1) == 27) break;
}


if (capCv.isOpened())
{
    capCv.release();
}


return 0;
```

}

What's the problem?

My guess is that ffmpeg could be the problem, but that's just a guess.

I use opencv320 and I also put opencv_ffmpeg320_64.dll in the same folder

Comment: the problem is that you haven't said what brand and model your camera is, and how it's attached (USB 2? USB 3? ethernet?) -- your webcam probably only supports those with specific **compressed** formats because of data rate through the wire. you can try setting the CAP_PROP_FOURCC. **the order** of set() calls may be important! use ffprobe to figure out what formats support what frame rates: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Capture/Webcam and https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/DirectShow

Comment: Fully agree to  @ChristophRackwitz. After setting the `CAP_PROP_FOURCC`, you should read out with `capCv.get(cv::CAP_PROP_FOURCC)` and see whether the setting of compressed mode was successful.